# How involved is tapping power from a device to add LED's?

Tags: led

I am thinking about doing a little hobby project (if it proves to be not so difficult) and I am not exactly sure where to start.  Macintosh computers  have an illuminated Apple logo, and there is a similar mod to illuminate the Apple icon on the back of iPhones, as in the following picture:

[image]
([source](http://www.cultofmac.com/135651/illuminate-your-iphone-4s-apple-logo-with-this-awesome-mod-but-be-quick/))

Obviously I will need a replacement plate for the back that will allow the light to shine through the Apple logo, as well as some LED's, and a few other things. The kits online range from $30.00 up and produce the illuminating in various ways. The concept seems fairly simple and doesn't seem like it would actually cost all that much to make your own "kit" to do this.

- Is it something practical as a side project?
- Would it be fairly inexpensive?
- Would it be a hassle?
- Would the risks of failure be high enough to not even attempt this?
- And if it is practical, what all do you guys think I would need? (besides the plate replacement and LED's)

Comment: I don't have an apple iphone or a mac so be patient with me and try explaining again what you are trying to do.

Comment: While the goal is obvious "Add a led to the back of an iPhone", the source of it on a macbook, from pretty much the first powerbooks and ibooks, is the backlight. It's not an individual led.

Comment: it seems, that your mind is already made up on building this project, so why ask for anyone's permission! Just do it.

Comment: You'd be surprised how fast shopping for a little this and that can add up to $30. Hobbyists get gouged left and right by the price elasticity of individual parts. The kit people know what they are doing when it comes to setting price points.

Comment: @Andyaka Angelatlarge edited my question to explain it better.

Answer (score 3):

Tapping power from any device is simple, as long as you can A) get a voltage you can use and B) draw less power than it safely can provide. The specifics vary by device, some simply do not have accessible voltage points.

Specifically for the iPhone glow mods, a small EL panel is tied to Gnd, and what seems to be a inverter for the screen (not backlight, as the glow mod is on for 15 seconds after the backlight is turned off.). **All you need for the electronics part of that kit would be an EL panel that works at the same frequency as that solder point.**

Update:
Actually, there seems to be different types of mods, or conflicting information. A different mod uses 6 small smd leds and a small sheet of diffuser for the mod. No visible resistors or regulator:
[image]

As to the updated post, the simplest thing to say specifically about doing this to an iPhone, from scratch is, you might save a few bucks, or kill your 500~700 dollar iPhone. I think that's a pretty high failure risk.

Comment: Yeah that's true. It would be cool to say that I did it myself, but then again I might have to replace my whole phone lol.